# Is this structure "It is adjective to verb" idiomatic?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure

I'd like to know if clauses such as "It is hard to judge." are idiomatic, so that I can say it's an example of intransitive use of "judge."

Additionally, it'd be great if you could tell me what this type of structure is called.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! My first impression was you were asking about transitive vs. intransitive usage of "judge", You later added a line in your question, making it vague. What do you mean "this type of structure"?

Comment: @Eddie Kal  It seems the person who has put the question just want to get it right what a designation is of this grammatical structure in the grammatical practice.

Comment: Yes, it is idiomatic, and an example of the verb 'judge' being used as intransitive. The type of the structure has many names in the grammar theory. A name depends on authorship of theories. It is called as an 'extraposed infinitive subject for  predicative constructions with linking to be' sometimes.

Comment: I don't think there's any doubt that this is a subject extraposition construction. I'd say that it's preferable to the non-extraposed "To judge is hard".